# Trying to create a batch file for maven project

Tags: eclipse, selenium, maven

When i do maven clean and maven install in pom.xml i get build success and all my test cases are running fine.Then in a notepad i wrote as below
d:
cd D:path of my project
mvn clean install

and saved it with .bat extension.But when i double click on the batch file it doesn't run.Please help.Many thanks in advance.

**Here is my pom.xml file**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>xyz</groupId>
      <artifactId>Abc</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      
      <properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/Able/TestRunner/ProjectExecution.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>
      
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
      </dependency>
      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng-->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
      </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>`enter code here`
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
      
      </dependencies>
      
       <build>
     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
    
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
     <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
     
     </build>
      
      
    </project>
```

[when i start the batch file this happens(a picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYsn4.png)

Comment: Please add the `bat` file and describe what happens when you start it.

Comment: @JFMeier i have edited the post with error

Answer (score 0):

So the Java on your machine is a JRE, not a JDK.

Install a JDK and put it on your PATH.